# Cleaning up the sweat & flux

Tags: cleaning, copper

What is a effective way to clean the inside of copper fittings after sweating them together?

[Edit: eye candy]

[See here for eye-candy](http://blog.deanandadie.net/2010/07/hard-plumbing-the-stand/).

[image: Plumbing]
[image: Plumbing]

Comment: Are we going to see some pics of what you just sweated together?  Or is this just a hypothetical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're not attached to anything, maybe soak them in PBW for 30 minutes? If they're attached in a system, run PBR through the system for a few minutes. Either way, then rinse, sani, and brew!

Comment: I have no idea, by the way. I'm just assuming this is a good solution because it works for just about everything else.

Comment: I recirculated PBW for five minutes, then rinsed.

Answer (score 0):

I've watched plumbers fix various pipe joints in the past, and they typically run water through them for a few minutes and then declare it good to go.